# Como usar função invertida neste caso de jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
// Aplicando CSS na Página de Eventos
$(".descr-eventos").on('mouseover', function(){
    $(this).find('.link-evento').addClass('blank'); 
}, function(){
    $(this).find('.link-evento').removeClass('blank');  
});
```

Eu quero que quando eu remover o mouse seja removida a classe `blank`. Como posso fazer?

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi, você quer usar o que seria o inverso de `mouseenter` (executa um evento quando o mouse é colocado sobre um elemento).

Utilize o evento `mouseleave`

Ele executa uma ação quando o mouse deixa um determinado elemento.

Exemplo:

```
$(".descr-eventos").on('mouseover', function(){
    $(this).find('.link-evento').addClass('blank'); 
}).on('mouseleave', function(){
    $(this).find('.link-evento').removeClass('blank');  
});
```

Veja funcionando no [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vzy5v5uL/)

Existe também o `mouseout`, que faz a mesma coisa, porém com algumas variações

Veja sobre isso aqui em [Diferença entre Mouseleave e Mouseout](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/75635/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-mouseleave-e-mouseout)