# Qual é a diferença entre mouseleave e mouseout?

Tags: jquery

No jQuery, qual é a diferença entre `mouseleave` e  `mouseout`?

Os dois eventos parecem fazer a mesma coisa!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basicamente,  unica diferença entre os dois é que, o `mouseleave` é disparado também nos elementos filhos do elemento selecionado, e o `mouseout` dispara apenas no elemento selecionado.

```js
x = 0;
y = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.over").mouseout(function(){
        $(".over span").text(x += 1);
    });
    $("div.enter").mouseleave(function(){
        $(".enter span").text(y += 1);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div class="over" style="background-color:lightgray;padding:20px;width:250px;float:left">
  <h3 style="background-color:white;">Mouseout disparado: <span></span></h3>
</div>

<div class="enter" style="background-color:lightgray;padding:20px;width:250px;float:right">
  <h3 style="background-color:white;">Mouseleave disparado: <span></span></h3>
</div>
```

Aqui você pode conferir mais sobre esses  dois eventos eventos:

[mouseout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseout)

[mouseleave](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseleave)

Answer (score 3):

Suponhamos que temos o seguinte HTML (onde cada div possui eventos mouseout, mouseleave atrelados):

```
<div id="outerBox">OuterBox
    <div id="innerBox">InnerBox
    </div>
</div>
```

- **Mouseout**: Quando o mouse entra em “outerBox” nenhum evento é ativado.
- Quando o mouse deixa “outerBox” e entra em "innerBox" o evento de “outerBox” é ativado.
- quando o mouse deixa “innerBox” e entra em “outerBox” o evento do "innerBox" é ativado seguido pelo evento do “outerBox”.
- quando o mouse deixa “outerBox” seu evento é disparado.
- **Mouseleave**: - Quando o mouse entra em “outerBox” nenhum evento é ativado.
- Quando o mouse deixa “outerBox” e entra em "innerBox" nenhum evento é ativado.
- quando o mouse deixa “innerBox” e entra em “outerBox” o evento do "innerBox" é ativado.
- quando o mouse deixa “outerBox” seu evento é disparado.

> Logo é possível notar que as diferenças entre ambas estão relacionadas a seus "filhos" "**mouseleave**" é disparado também nos elementos filhos enquanto o "**mouseover**" somente no elemento selecionado.

Fonte: http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/different-between-mouseout-and-mouseleave-in-jquery/